# Ajax wordpress : The data is not transmitted to the template

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

In my wordpress website I try to display posts after a category click.

This is my JS function :

```js
    function loading_posts_categories($) {

        $('#categories a').on('click', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
        
            var category = $(this).data('category');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: adminAjax.ajax_url, 
                data: {
                    action: 'fetch_posts_by_category',
                    category: category,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var container = $('#posts-container');
                    container.hide();
                    container.html(response.template).fadeIn();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log( xhr.responseText );
                }
           });
        });
    };
```

And this is my php function :

```php
function fetch_posts_by_category() {

    if (empty($_POST['category'])) {
        wp_send_json_error('Category not provided.');
    }

    $category = sanitize_text_field($_POST['category']);

    $posts = get_posts([
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'category_name' => $category,
    ]);

    ob_start();
    //require get_template_directory() . '/template-parts/template-posts-container.php';
    get_template_part('template-parts/template-posts-container', null, [ 'custom_posts' => $posts ] );
    $template_content = ob_get_clean();
    

    wp_send_json([
        'template'  => $template_content,
        ]
    );
    die();
}
```

I have this template template-posts-container.php :

```php
<div id="posts-container">
    <?php foreach ($custom_posts as $post): ?>
        <h2><?php echo esc_html($post['title']); ?></h2>
        <div class="post-content"><?php echo wp_kses_post($post['content']); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

And this is my template called template-posts (how can I do the link between this template and template-posts-container ?). This is this template who is display on my page.

```php
<?php $categories = get_categories(); ?>

<div id="categories">
   <ul>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
            <li><a href="#" data-category="<?= $category->slug; ?>"><?= $category->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="years-container"></div>
```

**My problem :**

When I dump the posts into my PHP function I get all the posts according to category displayed correctly.
However, the template remains empty. I can't pass my posts to my template.
Where is the problem ?

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: The arguments are passed in via the `$args` variable, not as globals. So your foreach loop should be looping over `$args['custom_posts']` and not `$custom_posts`.

Comment: That's true. I've found my mistake in the meantime, thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```php
<?php extract($args); ?>
<div id="posts-container">
    <?php foreach ($custom_posts as $post): ?>
        <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

In the template. Saved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your modify template-posts-container.php temaplte code, You should try

```
<div id="posts-container">
    <?php foreach ($custom_posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <h2><?php echo esc_html(get_the_title($post)); ?></h2>
        <div class="post-content"><?php echo wp_kses_post(get_the_content(null, false, $post)); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

> setup_postdata($post) to set up global post data. This allows you to
> use template tags like get_the_title() and get_the_content().
> get_the_title($post) and get_the_content(null, false, $post) are used
> to fetch the title and content of each post.